# Replacing / Manipulating element in html string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a html string (not DOM), that I want to manipulate using jquery. Why doesn't this work:

```
var html = '<div><h4><a class="preview-target" href="content.html">Headline</a></h4></div>';
console.log(html);

var elem = $('h4', $(html));
// replace "Headline" with "whatever" => Doesn't work
elem.replaceWith("whatever");

console.log(html);
```

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nachtigall/XpWdA/2/) for testing.

The above code is just a simplified example. The real html is much more complex, that is, I definitely need to rely on jQuery for manipulating the html string.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you modify the jQuery object, it will not change the value in the string literal.

You can use

```
var html = '<div><h4><a class="preview-target" href="content.html">Headline</a></h4></div>';
console.log(html);

var $html = $('<div />',{html:html});
// replace "Headline" with "whatever" => Doesn't work
$html.find('a').html("whatever");

console.log($html.html());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z9jes/)

Comment: "When you modify the jQuery object, it will not change the value in the string literal." Why is that? Seems like a bug to me?!

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't understand var $html = $('<div />',{html:html});  What exactly does this bit of code do? Looks like you create an object? What is the <div />  about?  Does that add to the original HTML or is it selecting the div within the existing string?

Comment: @AdamYoungers `$('<div />',{html:html});` - creates a dom div element, and set the value of `html` as its `innerHTML`....

Comment: *It will not change the value in the string literal* - important key is here. "$($('select').html())" will do the trick and do whatever you want like $($('select').html()).find('h4').remove()

Answer (score 6):

You can find the h4 then call the replaceWith method.

```
var html = $('<div><h4><a class="preview-target" href="content.html">Headline</a></h4></div>');

console.log(html.html());
html.find('h4').replaceWith('whatever')
console.log(html.html());
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XpWdA/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
var html = '<div><h4><a class="preview-target" href="content.html">Headline</a></h4></div>';
var replaced=html.replace("Headline","whatever");
console.log(replaced);
```

Try this

Comment: ok, but why isn't my above code not working? My code above is just a simplified example, the real code is much more difficult html that I cannot manipulate using simple `replace` method. So I need jQuery

Comment: @A.Wolff ok, but that would only work for my minimal working example code, not for my much more complex code. There I need to rely on jQuery. I updated the question with regards to this